# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "abcde"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am running my postgres server in a docker container and i am trying to connect it through spring boot but the error says password authentication failed for user even though i am using the correct password.What could be rhe problem ?

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/expensetrackerdb
spring.datasource.username=expensetracker
spring.datasource.password=password
#logging.level.org.springframework=debug
#@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class})
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.1</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>expense_tracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>expense_tracker</name>
    <description>REST API for Expense tracking</description>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
<!--       <dependency>-->
<!--          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>-->
<!--          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
<!--          <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--       </dependency>-->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <version>42.5.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried changing the md5 to password but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems odd that the error message is for user `abcde` when the user in your properties file is `expensetracker`.